# How do I periodically reload a web page in a Terminal web browser?

Tags: command-line, elinks, w3m

How do I schedule the reloading of a page when using a terminal browser?

using any of: Elinks, w3m etc

Comment: I chased an old document which mentioned "set document.browse.refresh = 1", however its "1" (true) by default and its to enable allowing the document to be refreshed by the webpage from javascript, rather than some auto refreshing feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, these browsers do not support programmed reloading, however it can easily be accomplished by using a terminal multiplexer like `tmux`. For example if you start the browser in one terminal like this:

```
tmux new-session -s browse 'w3m google.com'
```

Then you can send commands to it from a script or another terminal with the `send-keys` command. So to make `w3m` reload the current page do this:

```
tmux send-keys -t browse R
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Lynx the w3m browser can reload a page, when the page has the meta-refresh tag in its header. You just have to enable it in w3m's config file: Look for "meta_refresh 0" and change the value to "1": https://www.computerhilfen.de/english/w3m-browser-activate-meta-refresh.html

If a webpage has the meta-refresh-tag, it will reload it with the given time: Here the time is three seconds and the URL is https://askubuntu.com:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=https://askubuntu.com">
```